# Get boolean array (or generator) from pandas DataFrame index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have an indexed pandas DataFrame similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['good','good','bad'], 'nr':[0,1,2], 'value':[1,2,3]})

df.set_index(['type','nr'], inplace=True)

df
Out[153]:

        | value
type nr |
--------+-------
good  0 |   1
      1 |   2
--------+-------
bad   2 |   3
```

I want to plot the values (with matplotlib) together with an indicator 'good'/'bad'. For this indicator, a 0/1 numpy array would suffice -- 0 where the data is 'bad' and 1 where the data is 'good'. But the dataset is quite large and I would prefer a generator, not an actual array.

I don't know how to create this array/generator from `df`. I need to use it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(good_or_bad_indicator)
plt.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

Could someone please help?

PS: I would prefer a solution based on a lambda function, because in my real case there are more than two values in the 'type' column and I might want to design a more complex indicator to be plotted.

Comment: There's always `df.iteritems()`, but I suspect that the memory usage of the DataFrame is going to be negligible compared to plot.

Comment: @TomAugspurger : I tried, but `iteritems()` just returns a pair `(column_name, series_instance)`. I don't know how to use this to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods to get your indicator:

```
df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'good'
```

is the simplest. Also check out `isin` if you have more than one "good" option. You can also iterate over the index, if you want something more complex (instead of `x[0] ==` put a lambda or a method on x):

```
[x[0] == 'good' for x in df.index]
```

If you need the entire row, you can use `df.iterrows()`